# PixiJS and React-> Handle failure gracefully if the image fails to be loaded

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

I am building a React JS app and using Pixi to display the images.

I have this piece of code that loads the images from the API into the Pixi manifest:

```
const story_images: ResolverAssetsArray = []
fetched_data.stories.forEach((story) => {
    if (story.story_image !== null) {
        story_images.push({
            name: "story-" + story.id.toString(),
            srcs: story.story_image
        });
    }
});


assets_manifest.bundles.push({
    name: "story-icons",
    assets: story_images
});


await Assets.init({ manifest: assets_manifest });

Assets.backgroundLoadBundle("story-icons");
const storyAssets = await Assets.loadBundle("story-icons");
canvasManager.setAssets(storyAssets, mediaAssets);
```

But...if any of the images fail to load, I get the following error and the whole thing halts:

```
Error: [Loader.load] Failed to load <URL>
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Loader.ts:203:1
    at async Promise.all ...
```

Is there any way to handle this more gracefully and skip the target image or even better set a default image instead? If there is no option like that I plan to load image 1 by 1 and checking in try/catch if I can load them in assets maybe...